# Simulating a file input click with .click() does not work in iOS - Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, reactjs

I am using React to build a web-app wrapped with Cordova to be a native app on android/iOS. I am having trouble with specifically iOS, specifically with simulating a click on a file input with `.click()`

I am using this library: https://github.com/odysseyscience/react-s3-uploader

Here is my code, very simple:

`<button onClick={(e) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   $('#fileinput').click()
}} className='btn btn--no-bg btn--w-icon uploader'>`

The element with id `fileinput` is a rendered version of the react uploader, but in plain HTML looks like this:

`<input type="file" id="fileinput" class="hidden react-s3" accept="image/*">`

I have done a bunch of testing and the problem is occuring in the `.click()` jquery event. The first `onClick` is definitely being triggered, but nothing happens (in iOS) when `$('#fileinput').click()` is called.

This portion of code works in a web browser as well as in my android simulator, but once again *not* in my iOS simulator.

When I go into the console for all three environments (desktop, iOS, android), and run the code `$('#fileinput').click()` in the console, the input is clicked and the photo selection is triggered for android and desktop, but does nothing on iOS.

Ive done a bunch of research, a few solutions I found that dont work are: adding `pointer: cursor` to either the button or the input, changing the `button` to an `a` tag, changing `display:none` to `visibility: hidden` on the hidden input, and trying all different versions of `.click()` i could find (vanillaJS, `.trigger`, `.touchstart`, `.touchend`, `.live`, etc.)

Comment: you may try $('#fileinput').get(0).click(). Instead of jQuery try to use the basic js click method.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this worked:

```
$('#fileinput').trigger("click");
```

and don't hide the file input but css it off screen like:

```
#fileinput {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
}
```

I don't think you can trigger clicks on a hidden element in iOS

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
document.getElementById("fileinput").discpatchEvent(new Event("click"))
```